# Load testing enterprise server with webservices

Tags: web-services, soap, load-testing

I want to load test an enterprise server which is running 80 different SOAP webservices. All webservices need to be used at the same time. I want to register breaking point of the overall system.

I found some tools for testing a single webservice but not for all at the same time. Which tools can i use?

Answer (score 0):

Our tool http://www.stresstimulus.com can test multiple Web services at the same time. For each web service, create a separate test case http://support.stresstimulus.com/display/doc40/Creating+Multiple+Test+Cases

To do so, issue a SOAP request and record it with StresStimulus proxy, or import a Fiddler .saz capture file. 
By default, all test cases will have the same mix weight = 1, so load will be spread between them evenly. To customize the load distribution, adjust the mix weights. After that, you can ramp-up the load to reach a breaking point. You'll receive a separate performance report for each web service as well as consolidated report with response times, errors and other KPI.